# If the impulse response of a causal LTIC system is $h(t) = \delta(t) + \sin(t)u(t)$, is it marginally stable or unstable (BIBO)?

Tags: continuous-signals, linear-systems, laplace-transform, stability

If you take the $H(s) = \mathcal{L}[h(t)]$ the poles are on the imaginary axis so the system should be marginally stable, but is it?

Comment: The system is supposed to be causal so $h(t) = 0, \forall t < 0$. So yes, I meant $sin(t)u(t)$, sorry.

Comment: Okay, thanks for clarifying.

Answer (score 1):

The Laplace transform of the given impulse response, i.e., the transfer function of the corresponding system, has two poles on the imaginary axis. According to the [definition of marginal stability](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Marginal_stability#Continuous_time), that system is marginally stable.

It is, however, not BIBO stable, because given an input with a frequency equal to the frequency of the poles will result in an unbounded response. For a causal continuous-time LTI system to be BIBO stable, all its poles must be strictly in the left half-plane, i.e., their real parts must be negative.